# Ninject xml Inject from another class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject.web

I am trying to inject from another class library but it doesn't work, i am getting this error:
Couldn't resolve type 'BLL.UserBLL, MyProject.Core' defined in 'to' attribute.

XML:

```
<module name="MyModule">
  <bind service="IUserBLL, MyWebProject"
        to="BLL.UserBLL, MyProject.Core" name="UserBLL" />
</module>
```

So i am trying to use the class UserBLL in the namespace "BLL" in the external class library "MyProject.Core".

The MyProject.Core is refered in MyWebProject

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is the the MyProject.Core dll present in the MyWebProject output directory ? If not, try to copy the dll in the output directory to see if it changes something

Comment: Yes it is present in the output directory.

Comment: the "to" attribute handling is done here. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Xml/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Xml/Processors/BindingBuilderFactory.cs#L76
You may try to see the result of a `Type.GetType("BLL.UserBLL, MyProject.Core")` in your MyWebProject code  to see if your own app is able to load the library. Also, is the MyProject.Core in the same platform and .net version target as your MyWebProject ?

Comment: Everything seems good and if i change the XML file to have a class that doesn't exist it throuws an exception so it might work BUT when i try to inject it into a webservice (asmx) i get null for the instance.

Comment: It still doesn't work. 
A extra note is that i can see the binding of i debug and inspect the kernel so the mapping is made correctly.
I try to inject into a webservice (asmx), i've changed the inheritance to Ninject.Web.WebServiceBase and i am putting the attribute [Inject] to the property that i want to inject.
All this works if i use kernel.Bind() instead with the same class and interface.